# Getting 'CORS header missing' error in AWS IAM JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to get IAM access keys using AWS JS SDK but I am getting error, 'CORS header missing, request blocked' in browser console.

As there is no support for IAM in latest AWS SDK as mentioned in this link:
[AWS SDK Services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-services.html),
I have built JS SDK again including IAM following link : [Build AWS JS SDK](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/).

I know how to set CORS configuration for S3 buckets in AWS console but I am not getting where to set CORS configuration for IAM?

My js script:

```
<!-- Including Javascript AWS SDK -->
<script src="aws-sdk-2.5.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Setting AWS Credentials -->
<script>
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '<access Key id here>',        
secretAccessKey: '<secret access key here>'});

// Configuring region
AWS.config.region = '<region here>';
</script>

<script> 
  function listAccessKeys(){ 
            var iam = new AWS.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'}); 
            var params = { UserName: '<username here>' };
            iam.listAccessKeys(params, function(err, data) { 
              if (err){ 
                      alert(err); 
                      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred                            
              }else{ 
                    alert(data); 
                    console.log(data); 
              } 
         }); 
        } 
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The IAM API does not currently support CORS, see here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=749334

Which means that browsers implementing CORS won't allow calls to the IAM APIs no matter what you do, this is why the browser SDK does not include the IAM module.

Your best bet is to harass the AWS folks and let them know you want CORS support on the IAM APIs! You can do that on their support forums or talking directly with them!

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=4

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

set the endpoint manually and the CORS anywhere URL. (change your service endpoint and that's all)

AWS.config.endpoint = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://comprehendmedical.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"